# /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lboost_filesystem

Tags: compiling

I'm building a third-party application and it can not find boost_filesystem.  I'm running Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS  I already installed these:

```
apt-get -y install libboost-dev
apt-get -y install libboost-regex-dev
apt-get -y install libboost-system-dev
apt-get -y install libboost-thread-dev
```

Does anyone know how to get boost_filesystem?

Better yet, can anyone tell me how to figure this out for myself?

UPDATE: Boost is mostly a set of header files.  Most of it does not require compiled libraries.  However, boost_filesystem must be compiled.  I installed boost via apt-get, and it installed the boost-filesystem header files, but it never compiled boost_filesystem.  Is this a bug with the install packages?  Does anyone know how I can compile boost_filesystem from the apt-get installed packages?

Comment: On my installation of 14.04, `libboost-filesystem1.54-dev` provides the `libboost_filesystem.so.1.54.0` library, and is installed as a dependency of `libboost1.54-dev`, which in turn should have been installed as part of the dependency package `libboost-dev` which you have already installed. If that's not the case for you, then something must have gone astray (e.g. manually deleted files / packages) or the software you are trying to build is simply not looking in the right place.

Comment: All : `apt-get install libboost-all-dev` .... Or just  boost-filesystem : `libboost-filesystem-dev` http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=trusty&searchon=names&keywords=libboost